# Laravel Relation: Check if a slot is taken or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have relations setup in three tables

**Plate** model

```
/**
     * A plate belongsto an platecontainer
     * @return platecontainer relation
     */
    public function plateContainer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
    }

    /**
     * A plate belongsto slot
     * @return containerslots relations
     */
    public function containerSlots()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ContainerSlot');
    }
```

**PlateContainer** model

```
  public function plates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Plate');
    }

    /**
     * A plate Container has many slots in it.
     * @return containerslot model relation
     */
    public function containerSlots()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ContainerSlot');
    }
```

And finally **ContainerSlot** model

```
/**
     * A containerslot belongsTo plateContainer
     * @return platecontainer relation
     */
    public function plateContainer()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
    }

    /**
     * A containerslot has one plate
     * @return hasOne relation with plate model
     */
    public function plate()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Plate');
    }
```

Upon selection of an platecontainer, the user gets to see all the slots which are available and which are taken. How I might achieve this??

Here is my containerslot table

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('container_slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->tinyInteger('slots')->default(15);
            $table->boolean('taken');
            $table->integer('plate_container_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('plate_container_id')->references('id')->on('plate_containers');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Something like this

```
return   $p = \App\Models\PlateContainer::with('containerSlots.plate')->find(21);
```

will return only the plates associated with containerslots  but still don't know which plate in which slot.

Please help.

**UPDATE**: added tables

**Plates** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('serial_number');
        $table->string('crc-code', 50);
        $table->string('reason', 50)->nullable();
        //$table->tinyInteger('plate_container_slot')->nullable();
        $table->integer('stack_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('plate_container_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('container_slot_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('stack_id')->references('id')->on('stacks')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('plate_container_id')->references('id')->on('plate_containers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('container_slot_id')->references('id')->on('container_slots')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**platecontainer** tables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plate_containers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 25)->unique();
        //$table->tinyInteger('number_of_slots');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('material', 50);


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**containerslots** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('container_slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->tinyInteger('slots')->default(15);
        $table->boolean('taken');
        $table->integer('plate_container_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('plate_container_id')->references('id')->on('plate_containers');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent's `whereDoesntHave` query method to determine which container slots for given plate container have no related plates.

```
// select a container
$plateContainer = PlateContainer::find($id); 

// all slots that belong to given container that do not have a plate assigned
$freeSlots = $plateContainer->containerSlots()->whereDoesntHave('plate')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering! I have tried your suggested solution, however, it returns only empty array `[]`. I am not sure why, although I do have data in my DB. `Collection {#408
  #items: []
}` is what I am getting when i use dd `$freeslots`. How can I debug this?

Comment: You can always get the generated SQL by calling toSql() on the query builder. Execute that and paste the results: dd($plateContainer->containerSlots()->whereDoesntHave('plate')->toSql());

Comment: Actually, in your case there is a simpler way, I'll update the answer in a sec

Comment: Thanks! but I am afraid `$freeSlots = $plateContainer->containerSlots()->whereNull('plate_id')->get();` won't do it, because I don't have `plate_id` in containerslots table. I have updated the question with tables. I have tried  `dd($plateContainer->containerSlots()->whereDoesntHave('plate')->toSql());`as well. Any other solutions, please.

Comment: Ah, I thought the relation is the other way round. Anyway, could you paste the SQL that gets generated with toSql()? It should work, you should get sth like "select * from `container_slots` where (select count(*) from `plates` where `plates`.`container_slot_id ` = `container_slots`.`id`) < 1"

Comment: This the output  `"select * from `container_slots` where `container_slots`.`plate_container_id` = ? and `container_slots`.`plate_container_id` is not null and (select count(*) from `plates` where `plates`.`container_slot_id` = `container_slots`.`id` and `plates`.`deleted_at` is null) < 1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94909/discussion-between-user3641381-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Comment: Are you sure your data is ok? The query does what you need: For all container_slots that belong to given plate_container (`where container_slots.plate_container_id = ? and container_slots.plate_container_id is not null`) select the ones for which there are no undeleted plates that would point to this plate container (`(select count(*) from plates where plates.container_slot_id = container_slots.id and plates.deleted_at is null) < 1`)